# Get xml node value c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Let us consider the following xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <response success="true">
       <struct>value</struct>
   </response>
```

while parsing i am getting following error as

```
Root element is missing.
```

the code which i used was

```
foreach (XElement carselement in xdoc.Descendants("response"))
                {
                  String  value= carselement.Element("struct").Value;

                }
```

waiting for your solutions

Comment: How is `xdoc` loaded and what does it *really* contain? I would imagine it does *not* represent that XML.

Comment: @user2246674 ya thats the problem i am facing can i do it some other way

Comment: @GowthamanSS your code is working without problems.

Comment: @all thanks for your support i have missed  XDocument.Parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The XML input is not as expected (it is "empty")*** and the exception occurs during `XDocument.Load` (or `XDocument.Parse`, etc).

Ultimately `xdoc` *does* not contain what is expected - and the "suspect" lines never even run; again, this Exception is caused when the XML is *parsed*, not when it is enumerated/navigated. This scenario should be easily identified with an [*attached debugger*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173083%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or stack-trace.

Here is some minimal code that can be run in LINQPad as C# statements. I've modified it just enough to display nicely with dump. Note that *it runs as expected*.

```
var xmlStr = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>
   <response success=""true"">
       <struct>value</struct>
   </response>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
xdoc.Descendants("response")
    .Select(e => e.Element("struct").Value)
    .Dump();
```

Here is how the exception *can* be caused (and it has nothing to do with `Descendants` or other enumeration/navigation):

```
var xmlStr = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
// --> XmlException: Root element is missing
```

Comment: Nicely done! That would be so easy to debug, it's not as easy to guess and figure out with a "pencil and paper"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your XML is over simplified, and looks like this:

```
<!-- example -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response success="true">
    <struct>value1</struct>
</response>
<response success="true">
    <struct>value2</struct>
</response>
<response success="false">
    <struct>value3</struct>
</response>
```

In this case you are missing a `<responses></responses>` which wraps around the `response` array of elements.

BTW, your code should work also, if your XML file is really what you quote here. Do you try to manipulate the XML too?

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
if (xdoc == null) return;

XElement response = xdoc.Descendants("response").FirstOrDefault();
XElement structElement = response.Descendants("struct").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Note that multiple root elements results in "XmlException: There are multiple root elements."